# How to upload multiple files with simple form in symfony 3

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to create a form with multiple files (images) upload in Symfony 3 and and simple form (i'm not using symfony form builder), but i get only one file (the first file). i'm using POSTMAN for send files via post method.

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->files->get('images');

    $ext = $file->guessExtension();
    $file_name = time() . '.' . $ext;
    $path_of_file = 'uploads/test';
    $file->move($path_of_file, $file_name);

    var_dump($file);
    die();
}
```

Comment: Wheres the html for your form?

Comment: i'm using postman for send the images via post method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide enough information, but maybe the problem is that you didn't set key property as array in Postman like this 'images[]' - than your Symfony endpoint will get an array of UploadedFile objects with all the needed data about your files and you also need to put foreach in your code here:

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->files->get('images');
    foreach ($file as $item) {
    do some operations
}
```